# R 'gstat - Warning: singular model in variogram fit

Tags: r, kriging, variogram, gstat

I am trying to perform a kriging interpolation. But when it comes to the point when i want to fit the variogram to the model I get the following **warning**:
`In fit.variogram(vario, vgm("Sph")) : singular model in variogram fit`

I am not sure where I have to look at to solve the porblem.

**my data (these are just 10 / 216 lines):**

```
Place;Latitude;Longitude;Temperature;Humidity;Windspeed;AirPressure
Aachen;50.77999878;6.09999990;3;93;15;1020
Abbikenhausen;53.52999878;8.00000000;7.9;83;1.9;1022
Adelbach;49.04000092;9.76000023;3.1;91;8.0;1014
Adendorf;51.61999893;11.69999981;1.9;76;2.9;1018
Alberzell;48.45999908;11.34000015;4.6;97;1.9;1012
Altenstadt;47.83000183;10.86999989;3.8;90;3.1;1012
Altersteeg;51.58000183;6.32000017;4.4;89;1.0;1017.5
Angermuende;53.02999878;14.00000000;1.5;89;1.0;1020
Arnsberg;51.11999893;7.32999992;2.3;100;13.0;1018
```

**my code:**

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(gstat)

WU_data <- read.csv(file = "./WU_Data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
WU_data <- WU_data[complete.cases(WU_data),]

min_lon <- min(WU_data$Longitude)
max_lon <- max(WU_data$Longitude)
min_lat <- min(WU_data$Latitude)
max_lat <- max(WU_data$Latitude)

Longitude.range <- as.numeric(c(min_lon,max_lon))
Latitude.range <- as.numeric(c(min_lat,max_lat))

grd <- expand.grid(Longitude = seq(from = Longitude.range[1], to = Longitude.range[2], by = 0.1), 
                   Latitude = seq(from = Latitude.range[1],to = Latitude.range[2], by = 0.1))  # expand points to grid
coordinates(grd) <- ~Longitude + Latitude
gridded(grd) <- TRUE

WU_data_spatial <- WU_data
coordinates(WU_data_spatial) = ~Longitude + Latitude

vario <-  variogram(Temperature ~1, WU_data_spatial)
vario.fit <- fit.variogram(vario, vgm("Sph"))
```

**plot(vario):**

[image]

Comment: Its a warning so it might not *be* a problem. What does the variogram look like when you plot it? What does the fitted variogram  look like? Maybe you need to adjust the bins of your variogram? Maybe there's just no spatial correlation in the data? (Bonus maybe: maybe you should convert your lat-long to something cartesian)

Comment: There's a paragraph starting "On singular model fits..." in the "Note:" section of `help(fit.variogram)` which you should read.

Comment: That's a nice looking variogram - you might even want to go out to a further distance to see if it levels off. Is it anywhere near `var(W_data_spatial$Temperature)` yet? And what does the fitted variogram model look like on top of that and what do the parameters look like? Show us the `vario.fit` object.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple data rows for the same coordinates?

Answer (score 10):

Some has already been said by Spacedman in the comments. This warning may not pose a problem, if the variogram *looks* good. A good option might be to initialize some of the variogram parameters in `vgm("Sph")`.
I usually take these values as default:

```
vario <-  variogram(Temperature ~1, WU_data_spatial)
vario.fit <- fit.variogram(vario, vgm(psill=max(vario$gamma)*0.9, model = "Sph", range=max(vario$dist)/2, nugget = mean(vario$gamma)/4))
```

and change them (or set some of them to NA) until I reach a satisfying result. Although I don't have so much experience as to demonstrate it in this particular case. Also the results would differ on this small sample of data and the whole dataset, on which you may achieve a better fit.

Personally, I would use the package `automap` and the function `autofitVariogram` to do this.

```
library(automap)

vario.fit = autofitVariogram(Temperature~1,
                             WU_data_spatial,
                             model = c("Sph"),
                             kappa = c(0.05, seq(0.2, 2, 0.1), 5, 10),
                             fix.values = c(NA, NA, NA),
                             start_vals = c(NA,NA,NA),
                             verbose = T)

plot(vario, vario.fit$var_model, main = "Fitted variogram")
```

Which gives the following result:
[image: Variogram fitted using autofitVariogram]

Looking at the dots of the empirical variogram I would think that the spatial correlation is rather poor, but again - I don't feel experienced enough to make any conclusions.